# Querying NHibernate on a nullable datetime

Tags: nhibernate, nullable

I'm having a heck of a time returning a few rows from my in-memory sqlite db that mocks an oracle db. I'm writing an NHibernate query to pull up rows by a nullable DateTime. I think I have it mapped correctly. Have a look:

The data object property:

```
public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> RequiredInstallDt { get; set; }
```

The mapping:

```
Map(x => x.RequiredInstallDt).Column("REQUIRED_INSTALL_DT").Nullable();
```

There's two rows in the db. One that should be pulled up and one that shouldn't. The date I'm asking for is **2012-8-1**. There's no time value and there isn't one in the db, which I've been able to verify. One row has Aug 1 and the other doesn't. I'm expecting one record returned.

If I say:

```
IList<Request> ra = new RequestDAO().ListAll();
```

which is a known working method in the same call as my query, I get the two records as expected.

I've tried several versions of the same query, using linq, hql, and the CreateCriteria versions. The result is almost always the same. I get 0 records back (the other way is a NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException so that's a PEBKAC). Here's one of those query versions:

```
        DateTime installDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1);
        var requests = session.CreateCriteria<Request>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Ge("RequiredInstallDt", installDate))
            .Add(Restrictions.Lt("RequiredInstallDt", installDate.AddDays(1)))
            .List<Request>();
```

Thanks for reading.. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `not null` restriction.  Your query could be

```
DateTime installDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1);
var requests = session.CreateCriteria<Request>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Ge("RequiredInstallDt", installDate))
        .Add(Restrictions.Lt("RequiredInstallDt", installDate.AddDays(1)))
        .Add(Restriction.IsNotNull("RequiredInstallDt"))
        .List<Request>();
```